Is it possible to throw an exception with subscript?
I have written code below in Swift 5.10 to store and retrieve Codable data from UserDefaults by giving key value in the subscript, but there is some compile time error:

Expected '->' for subscript element type
Expected type

Error Message Screenshot
This is the code:
import Foundation

extension UserDefaults {
    private func setValue<E: Encodable>(_ object: E?, forKey key: String) throws {
        if object == nil {
            return removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
        
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
        self.set(data, forKey: key)
    }

    private func object<D: Decodable>(forType type: D.Type, forKey key: String) throws -> D? {
        guard let data = self.data(forKey: key) else {return nil}
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(D.self, from: data)
    }
    
    public subscript<C: Codable>(key: String) (throws) -> C? {
        get {
            return try object(forType: C.self, forKey: key)
        } set {
            try setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

The code written below is a simple example of how I think it should be working if there wasn't this error:
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

// Storing a Codable object
let person = Person(name: "Alice", age: 30)
do {
    try UserDefaults.standard["person"] = person
} catch {
    print("Error storing person:", error)
}

// Retrieving a Codable object
do {
    if let storedPerson: Person = try UserDefaults.standard["person"] {
        print("Retrieved person:", storedPerson)
    } else {
        print("No person object found in UserDefaults")
    }
} catch {
    print("Error retrieving person:", error)
}


Currently, subscripts can only have a throwing getter, not a throwing setter. The same is true for computed properties.

It is probably reasonable to use try! or call fatalError in this case. Your input confirms to Encodable so it is unlikely that the coding will fail and if it does a crash will help you find the issue during development.

Swift does not "throw exceptions". It throws errors as a form of flow control. An exception is basically a crash condition raised by the runtime (eg an array out of bounds, divide by zero, that sort of thing).

I wrote a workaround by using closure as parameter

You can mark the getter as throws:
public subscript<C: Codable>(key: String) -> C? {
    get throws {
        return try object(forType: C.self, forKey: key)
    }
}

But setters cannot throw errors, as of Swift 6.0.
You have a few options:

Expose the private setValue method you wrote. In fact, I'd split this up into a setValue and a removeValue method.
Crash the program with fatalError()
Catch the error in the setter, log a message, but do nothing otherwise.
The SwiftyUserDefaults package uses assertionFailure(), which is kind of a combination of the above two options. Crash the program when debugging, but does nothing on optimised builds.


You don't need SwiftyUserDefaults to get the behavior of assertFailure(); just use the built-in Swift call assert().

@matt I don't mean to say that SwiftyUserDefaults is needed. I was just using that as an example, to demonstrate that other people has chosen to use assertionFailure() before.
